# C How do I get scanf to stop on blank/space?

Tags: c, scanf, space

I need my scanf to stop when it findes a spac/blank.

For exsample

If I type in "E E", I only need 1 "E", so it has to stop at space/blank.

```
char end[] = "E";
char end1[] = "End";
char info[] = "";

while(run) {
 scanf("%s", &info);
 ...
 else if(strcmp(info, end) == 0 || strcmp(info, end1) == 0) {
    end_of_turn();
 }
 ...
}
```

Now the problem here is that If I type in "E E", it will run "end_of_turn" twice.

Does anyone know why it is so?

Edit:

Okay I can't break the while loop, because that would stop the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `break` to break out of the `while` loop? after calling `end_of_turn()`

Or use a `goto` statement if you do not want to break out of the loop.

You can also get all the characters from the input stream and then discard them using the code: `while(getchar() != '\n') ;`

Comment: Isnt `break` basically a `goto` statement?

Comment: break will get OUT of the `while()` loop, with goto he can move anywhere he wants .. even within the loop

Comment: @user2041265 well, I suggest you use the last method.. that seems more appropriate in your end.

Comment: use `while(getchar() != '\n');` just after `scanf("%s",&info);`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is possible to use the `%[` format specifier to only match certain characters. To exclude spaces, I think you would use `%[^ ]`.

Answer (score -1):

Loop through the string stored in `info` searching for the space character `' '`, if you find it then set the rest of the string to `\0`

Comment: `scanf()` breaks at first whitespace. The problem is, the data entered by the user during `scanf()`ing remains in the input buffer.. causing mayhem